# How to find duplicate rows in a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, duplicates, having-clause

I have a table called `PropertyValues` with 4 columns

`Name`, `PropertyID`, `PropertyUnitID`, `PropertyTypeID`

Since there are 19422 rows in there, I want to know if there are any duplicate entries, which have the exact same value in all 4 columns.

I know I can do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) AS Expr1
FROM PropertyValues
WHERE (Name = 'Abc') 
  AND (PropertyID = '5') 
  AND (PropertyUnitID = '15') 
  AND (PropertyTypeID = '37')
```

Which tells me how many times is this combination of values in the table - But this is of course for only one combination of values.

I basically need it to tell me which row is more than once in the Table, and return the ID of those rows, preferably grouped by Name. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

One option uses aggregation:

```
select Name, PropertyID, PropertyUnitID, PropertyTypeID, count(*)
from PropertyValues
group by Name, PropertyID, PropertyUnitID, PropertyTypeID
having count(*) > 1
```

This brings tuples that occur on more than one row.

If you want an overal count of such rows, use another level of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (
    select Name, PropertyID, PropertyUnitID, PropertyTypeID
    from PropertyValues
    group by Name, PropertyID, PropertyUnitID, PropertyTypeID
    having count(*) > 1
) t
```

Finally, if you want entire rows, then use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select p.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by Name, PropertyID, PropertyUnitID, PropertyTypeID) rn
    from PropertyValues p
) p
where rn > 1
order by Name, PropertyID, PropertyUnitID, PropertyTypeID
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I run the second code, I get the count 5899 returned. When I want to check the rows with your third code, I get an error `SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane.` - I run it inside SSMS. Is it because there are more rows that I didn't mention in the question because they are not of interest for the comparison? - Gotta go to sleep now I'll check back tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select pv.*
from (select pv.*,
             count(*) over (partition by Name, PropertyID, PropertyUnitID, PropertyTypeID) as cnt
      from propertyvalues pv
     ) pv
where cnt >= 2;
```

This returns the entire row.  You can just use `select id` if you want only the `id`.